# Multithreading for faster downloading

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, urllib2, urllib

How can I download multiple links simultaneously? My script below works but only downloads one at a time and it is extremely slow. I can't  figure out how to incorporate multithreading in my script.

The Python script:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html as html
import urlparse
import os, sys
import urllib2
import re

print ("downloading and parsing Bibles...")
root = html.parse(open('links.html'))
for link in root.findall('//a'):
  url = link.get('href')
  name = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-1]
  dirname = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('.')[-1]
  f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  s = f.read()
  if (os.path.isdir(dirname) == 0): 
    os.mkdir(dirname)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
  articleTag = soup.html.body.article
  converted = str(articleTag)
  full_path = os.path.join(dirname, name)
  open(full_path, 'w').write(converted)
  print(name)
```

The HTML file called `links.html`:

```
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.1.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.1.nmv-fas</a>

<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.2.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.2.nmv-fas</a>

<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.3.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.3.nmv-fas</a>

<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.4.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.4.nmv-fas</a>
```

Comment: You haven't even tried anything yet, so you don't actually have a problem we can help with.

Comment: open(full_path, 'wb').write(converted) !!! you want to download binary files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the consumer - producer problem - see wikipedia

You may use

```
import Queue, thread

# create a Queue.Queue here
queue = Queue.Queue()

print ("downloading and parsing Bibles...")
root = html.parse(open('links.html'))
for link in root.findall('//a'):
  url = link.get('href')
  queue.put(url) # produce




def thrad():
  url = queue.get() # consume
  name = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-1]
  dirname = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('.')[-1]
  f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  s = f.read()
  if (os.path.isdir(dirname) == 0): 
    os.mkdir(dirname)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
  articleTag = soup.html.body.article
  converted = str(articleTag)
  full_path = os.path.join(dirname, name)
  open(full_path, 'wb').write(converted)
  print(name)

thread.start_new(thrad, ()) # start 1 threads
```

Comment: I am getting this error `NameError: name 'queue' is not defined
` and if I capitalize "Queue" I get this error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'put'`

Comment: Do you really want to have a function named `thread` when you've imported a module of the same name?

Comment: right. this was only a suggestion of structure and not a solution since he knows about multithreading.

Comment: @Blainer, The first line *should* probably read `from Queue import Queue` (for python 2.X) and `from threading import Thread`, then the last line should be `Thread.start_new(thread,())` ... I think.  (I don't really use `threading` so I don't know for sure.)

Comment: @user1320237, we're here to solve problems.  Handwaving and theoretical solutions are not going to help

Comment: I am getting this `TypeError: unbound method put() must be called with Queue instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`

Comment: @blainer replace Queue.put with queue.put bye i have to leave

Answer (score 9):

I use `multiprocessing` for parallelizing things  -- for some reason I like it better than `threading`

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html as html
import urlparse
import os, sys
import urllib2
import re
import multiprocessing


print ("downloading and parsing Bibles...")
def download_stuff(link):
  url = link.get('href')
  name = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-1]
  dirname = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('.')[-1]
  f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  s = f.read()
  if (os.path.isdir(dirname) == 0): 
    os.mkdir(dirname)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
  articleTag = soup.html.body.article
  converted = str(articleTag)
  full_path = os.path.join(dirname, name)
  open(full_path, 'w').write(converted)
  print(name)

root = html.parse(open('links.html'))
links = root.findall('//a')
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5) #use 5 processes to download the data
output = pool.map(download_stuff,links)  #output is a list of [None,None,...] since download_stuff doesn't return anything
```

Comment: I am getting this error `AssertionError: invalid Element proxy at 163319020`

Comment: @Blainer : That's a little strange (although I don't know how lxml.html works, so maybe it isn't...).  You could try passing the url's instead of the links.  It's possible that some information lxml.html keeps some sort of proxy/handle on the position in the file which isn't being pickled/unpickled properly by `multiprocessing`.  If link.get returns a string, that should play a little more nicely...

Answer (score 3):

In 2017 there are some other options now,  like asyncio and ThreadPoolExecutor.

Here is an example of ThreadPoolExecutor (included in Python futures)

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def download(url, filename):
    ... your dowload function...
    pass

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=12) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(download, url, filename)
    print(future.result())
```

submit() function will submit the task to a queue. (queue management is done for you)

```
Python version 3.5 and above:
if max_workers is None or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the 
machine, multiplied by 5.
```

You can set max_workers, a few times the number of CPU cores in practice, do some tests to see how faw you can go up, depending on context-switching overhead.

For more info:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html