# Multithreaded Web Scraper to store values to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

I have built a webscraper (using Python 3.4) to extract data from webpages and store it as a Pandas dataframe (prior to saving in an excel file). This is working successfully. However, the number of pages I would like to scrape has grown(>100k), which means that my current single-threaded approach is taking far too long to complete.

The URLS I need to scrape are known beforehand; a selection of my current code implementation is below:

```
For a in UrlRefs: # This is the masterlist of URLs to scrape (there are around 5000)
         for i in SecondRefs.index # For each of the main pages, there are 29 subpages. The subpage references are contained in a Pandas dataframe 'SecondRefs' along with a description of the webpage. 

             #the OpenPages function actually performs the webscraping (using BeautifulSoup to parse the pages)
             TempDF = OpenPages(a, SecondRefs.iloc[i,0],SecondRefs.iloc[i,1])
             MainDF=pd.concat([MainDF,Players],ignore_index=True)
```

I have no prior experience using multi-threading in Python, but my initial guess was that the 29 subpages could be multithreaded - I had attempted to do this as follows:

```
#code modified from http://www.quantstart.com/articles/Parallelising-Python-with-Threading-and-Multiprocessing
jobs=[]
        for i in range(1, 29):
            thread = threading.Thread(target=OpenPages(a,SecondRefs.iloc[i,0],SecondRefs.iloc[i,1]))
            jobs.append(thread)
            print("thread ",i)
        # Start the threads  
        for j in jobs:
            j.start()

        #Ensure all of the threads have finished
        for j in jobs:
            j.join()

        MainDF=pd.concat([MainDF,jobs],ignore_index=True)
```

The above approach produced errors when running and also did not seem to actually speed up the processing (it took around 20s to create the threads, at which point the error arose; ignoring the error, this is no faster than a single process)

My questions are the following:

1) How can I best implement multi-threading in my code to speed up the processing?

2) How can I then combine the returned values from each of the threads back into the main Pandas Dataframe?

Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT:**

Thank you for the replies.

For the record, I have reached the following solution for my problem (although please feel free to comment/critique, if you wish).

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from random import randrange
 pool = ThreadPool(processes=29)
        thread=[]
        for i in range(1, 29):
            thread.append(pool.apply_async(OpenPages, (a,SecondRefs.iloc[i,0],SecondRefs[i,1])))
            time.sleep(randrange(25,35)/100)

        # Start the threads    
        for i in range(1, 29):
            MainDF=pd.concat([MainDF,thread[i].get()],ignore_index=True)

        pool.close()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python multithreading for faster downloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505654/python-multithreading-for-faster-downloading)

Answer (score 0):

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=OpenPages(a,SecondRefs.iloc[i,0],SecondRefs.iloc[i,1]))
```

should be

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=OpenPages, args=(a,SecondRefs.iloc[i,0],SecondRefs.iloc[i,1]))
```